# How can I divide data separated by commas on different lines

Tags: php, csv

I have this script that extracts a .csv file from the database that holds data for different locals that a user has logged into. The .csv files come like this:

```
"id_user";"id_local"
"1";""
"2";"2,3,4"
"3";""
"5";"2,5"
"10";""
"13";"2"
"14";"5"
"15";"2"
"16";"1"
"20";"2"
"21";""
```

As you can se, it get one register per user
But, to manipulate it properly, we need it like this:

```
"id_user";"id_local"
"2";"2"
"2";"3
"2";"4"
"5";"2"
"5";"5"
"13";"2"
"14";"5"
"15";"2"
"16";"1"
"20";"2"
```

So, I need to create a function that deletes users with no local and splits different locals of the same user in different registers. Does anyone knows how can I do it?

Here is the code I have so far but I'm not sure if I'm on the right way:

```
function fix_local_secundario(){
    $filename = "local_secundario.csv";
    $file_locais = file_get_contents($filename);
    $locais = explode("\n", $file_locais);
    // $pattern = "/,/";
    // $replacement = "\"\n;\"";
    while ($line = current($locais)) {
        $line = str_getcsv($line, ';', '"','\n');
        // $line = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $line);
        var_dump($line);
        echo "\n";
        next($locais);
    }

}
```

Comment: have you looked into php explode() function ? Look at the answer that I gave to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133184/how-to-convert-string-from-mysql-to-associative-array-in-php/18133294#18133294 see if you can customize that solution to this problem.

Comment: Are you really using '\n' to escape quotes inside quotes? Especially as you're limited to a single character for escaping?

Comment: @Maximus2012 I tried using it, Will take a look on your answer and see if I can adapt it

Comment: @MarkBaker It is because I was testing it on terminal instead of browser, but I've changed that already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and see if this works:

```
function fix_local_secundario(){
    $filename = "local_secundario.csv";
    $file_locais = file_get_contents($filename);
    $locais = explode("\n", $file_locais);
    while ($line = current($locais)) {
        // do first split on ; character
        $arr1 = explode(";", $line);
        // if the part after ; is not empty for this line
        if ($arr1[1]!='""'){
            // split it further on , character
            $arr2 = explode(",", $arr1[1]);
            foreach ($arr2 as $key => $val){
                if($val[0] != '"'){
                    $val = '"'.$val;
                }
                if($val[strlen($val)-1] != '"'){
                    $val = $val . '"';
                }
                echo $arr1[0] . ";" . $val . "<BR>";
            }
        }
        next($locais);
    }
}
```

Once this basic piece is working, you should change it to return values rather than echo values since this code is part of a function as per updates made to your question.

Comment: not really, it returns the registers in the same line but separated by " " instead of ","

Comment: I think that is just a minor formatting issue. Look at the update that I made to the code.

Comment: Almost this! I'm jus't working on realizing why it keeps showing the empty ones even with `!=""` ou `!isempty()`

Comment: I think the edits that you are suggesting to this answer are complicating it. You might want to test the changes with your code first and make changes to it accordingly. I have rolled back the answer to previous revision for the time-being.

Comment: Already tested them, the last edit is necessary to remove the registers with empty id_local and because the registers created from the last `explode()` don't come properly wrapped by '""'

Comment: ok. In that case you can update your question with the last edit if you want.

Answer (score 0):

What about this…

```
$f = fopen("myfile.csv", "r");
while($row = fgetcsv($f, 0, ";")){
  $locals = explode(",", $row[1]);
  if (count($locals)>1){
    foreach($locals as $local)
      // iterate with $row[0] and $local
  }elseif($row[1] != "")
      // use $row[0] and $row[1]

}
```